# 0 supported device on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, apk

```
Gradle.build (App level)
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "iadsa.my.dailyexpenses"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/jexcel_android.jar')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.9'
}

Manifest file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="iadsa.my.dailyexpenses">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25"
        android:maxSdkVersion="25" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".application.AppApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".activities.StartUpActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ExpenseActivity"
            android:label="@string/exp_activity_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.AllExpenseActivity"
            android:label="@string/all_exp_activity_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ExpenseDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/activity_exp_details_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ExpenseAnalysisActivity"
            android:label="@string/analysis_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ContactUsActivity"
            android:label="@string/action_contact_us"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have uploaded apk on google play. And it is not supporting a single device. I am not able to fix issue. Please any one can help me regarding the issue. I will be thankful to the person. Please I need it immediately.

Screenshot of play store apk info.
[image]

Comment: when you uploaded the apk?

Comment: Yesterday night first version, Then again today another updated version. But still have no clue why this is happening.

Comment: today updated version will be reflected only by tomorrow.

Comment: It is now fully published in play store and still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It will not reflect immediately in dashboard when you upload the apk file.

They are supposed to be updated once every 24 hours. If it's your first apk, then it will take some time to change it to published version.

Moreover to track analytics, support device etc., it takes 24 hours to update. Possibly you can check it by today night or tomorrow morning for your previous version which you uploaded.

It's better to use Google analytics or flurry or any other analytics library to track instantly when user uses the app.

Comment: The problem is when I try to download by using its link, it's showing incompamtible with device. And I have also checked on manage device section. It is showing 0 supported device.

Comment: what's your device version? which device you tested?

Comment: My device is 6.0.

Comment: whether you checked the version name and code in playstore? is this one?  versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.2" please cross verify it..

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I have added an external library(JExcelApi). And that was using using log4j-1.2.16.jar and this was showing in native platform. That is why supported device was 0. 
When I removed this library. Supported device is 12K+.

[image]